# How to force scroll in inner div rather than browser window?

Tags: css

In the markup below, when I minimizes the browser window, I see scroll in the browser window scrolling rather than the scroll within the div from the overflow-y: scroll. How can I make it scroll in the inner scroll without doing anything to the body element?

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
line<br/>
line<br/>
line<br/>
line<br/>
line<br/>
line<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Without applying styles to the html and body elements, you are going to need to use some javascript. You could attach a function to the window's resize event that would size the height of the div to the height of the window if it gets smaller than a certain height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the height of the `<div>`

```
<div style="height:50px; overflow-y: scroll;">
```

Comment: But in the MacOS the scroll not appears? Any idea?

Comment: Sorry Im using Windows so I cant suggest anything for Mac :(

Comment: Actually you're right. When you set a height and minimize the browser window, scroll on the div is not scrolling...